# adaptive training rate optimizer.minimize

Tags: python, tensorflow

Having a function like this:

```
for i in range(0,200):
    train = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[tf_weights])
    print(loss().numpy())
    current_learning_rate = opt._decayed_lr(tf.float32)
    print(current_learning_rate)
```

The loss function is not a classification problem.
Do i need to overwrite model.fit() or is there a simpler way to achieve the adaptive learning rate.
I guessed, that opt.minimize() does not use adaptive learning rate.

Answer (score 0):

To create an addaptive learning_rate you can use custom callbacks in tensorflow.

As an example:

```
def CustomCallback(tf.keras.callvacks.Callback):
    on_epoch_end(self,logs=None):
       lr=float(tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.optimizer.learning_rate))
       decay_rate=0.5
       new_lr=self.schedule(epoch,lr)*decay_rate
       tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr,new_lr)
       print("Epoch:{},Current lr:{}".format(epoch,new_lr))

...
```

After creating the model:

```
model.fit(...,callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```